# Paypal adaptive payments by gift certificates

Tags: paypal, certificate, chained-payments, gift

How can I implement the **PayPal** chained payment by gift certificates?

There is no way to choose "**Gift certificate**" as a payment method during the adaptive payments, e.g. [chained payment](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment?interactive=ON&env=sandbox).

See the [Screenshot of the window after clicking to change the payment method][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybZtt.png)

Let me know if you need more details, I will provide them.